# Call data from server with Retrofit, RXJava and Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi i'm having some trouble to call data from server with retrofit and rxjava and show it on my layout. I'm new to kotlin development so its kinda confusing me. My problem is i'm able to call data from server but when i try to show it on my layout, it shows nothing. Here are  my code :

My model :

```
data class StackOverFlowCoba(

@field:SerializedName("quota_max")
val quotaMax: Int? = null,

@field:SerializedName("quota_remaining")
val quotaRemaining: Int? = null,

@field:SerializedName("has_more")
val hasMore: Boolean? = null,

@field:SerializedName("items")
val items: List<ItemsItem?>? = null
```

)

My presenter :

```
class MainPresenter : BasePresenter<StackOverFlowView> {

var modelView : StackOverFlowView?=null
val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

override fun onAttach(view: StackOverFlowView) {
    modelView = null
}

override fun onDettach() {
    modelView = null
}

fun getData()
{
    compositeDisposable.add(RetrofitHttp.stackOverFlow.getdata().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe({
                t: StackOverFlowCoba? -> modelView?.onSuccess(t?.items)
            }
                    ,{t: Throwable? ->   modelView?.onError()})
    )
}
```

}

my View interface:

```
interface StackOverFlowView : BaseView {

fun onSuccess(data : List<ItemsItem?>?)
fun onError()
```

}

my activity code :

```
class Main : AppCompatActivity(),StackOverFlowView {

lateinit var mainPresenter : MainPresenter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.coba_stackoverflow)

    initPresenter()
    toast("something adajfaosdpa")
}

private fun initPresenter()
{
    mainPresenter = MainPresenter()
    mainPresenter.getData()
}

override fun onSuccess(data: List<ItemsItem?>?) {
    user_id.text = data!![0]!!.owner!!.displayName
    toast("something basdsadjk")
}

override fun onError() {
    toast("something error")
}

override fun onAttachView() {
    mainPresenter.onAttach(this)
    mainPresenter.getData()
}

override fun onDettachView() {
    mainPresenter.onDettach()
}

override fun onStart() {
    onAttachView()
    super.onStart()
}

override fun onStop() {
    onDettachView()
    super.onStop()
}
```

}

when i check it on my logcat, everything is fine and my code can call data from server but i don't know why i'm unable to show it on my layout. Please help me, thank u in advance!

Comment: Update your onattach code in MainPresenter as below as you have forgotten to init modelView with view like this:
override fun onAttach(view: StackOverFlowView) {
    modelView = view
}